# exception java.lang.NullPointerException in servlet jsp and servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a source code Servlet.

```
SinhVien sv= new SinhVien();
    String url="../lienhepage.jsp";
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    //RequestDispatcher rD;
    //HttpSession session;
    if(request.getParameter("searchword")!= ""){
        String result= "";
        result= ZendCodeHTML.ZendCodeTag(sv.getDataTag(request.getParameter("searchword")));
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
        response.getWriter().write(result);
    }
    if(request.getParameter("NienKhoa") != ""){
        List<String> result= getData(request.getParameter("NienKhoa"));
        session.setAttribute("tieude", result.get(0)); 
        session.setAttribute("danhsachsinhvien", result.get(1)); 
        session.setAttribute("cacmongiangday", result.get(2)); 
        session.setAttribute("noidunghuongdanmonhoc", result.get(3));     
    }
    RequestDispatcher rD= request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
    rD.forward(request, response);
```

When i click link in page jsp has url="../lienheservlet?NienKhoa=2010-2015" then code servlet run normal. But when code run function `rD.forward(request, response);` then have exception like that:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
javacore.controller.lienheservlet.doGet(lienheservlet.java:115)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

I don't know why? please help me!

Comment: What does the javadoc of `getRequestDispatcher` say?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis when i debug run function  RequestDispatcher rD= request.getRequestDispatcher(url); done then rD= null; i don't know why?

Comment: What does the javadoc of `getRequestDispatcher` say?

Comment: obviously the URL is not correct...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the url is not right,

try not to use relative path, but absolute path. (e.g. "/lienhepage.jsp")

Answer (score 0):

check if the `url` is correct (it seems its a relative path so check again) that means that jsp file is resolvable using that relative path.

`getRequestDispatcher` will return null if it cannot create a wrapper for that url

That's the possible reason to get `null` at

```
RequestDispatcher rD= request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
```